# Group lines in Report Designer

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

I have corrected my sql query and get table 1.
Help me please change table 1 in order to get table 2. I think that i need to group "employee" lines, but how can i do that in Report Designer в Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 I don't know

```
Table1

USER1,0.00%,1

USER1,100.00%,1

USER1,100.00%,1

USER1,100.00%,1

USER1,0.00%,1

USER1,100.00%,1

USER1,0.00%,1

USER2,0.00%,1

USER2,100.00%,1

USER2,0.00%,1


Table2

USER1,80.00%,7

USER2,100.00%,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a query then group the same items in your table.

> Group by USER and sum the percentage and the number.